# Meteor: Using template variables in javascript upon template being rendered

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I want to modify the DOM using javascript upon the template being loaded (rendered). However, I can't seem to get the variables which were passed to the template in the first place. It seems that the only place I can use those variables are in the HTML template itself or in the template helpers. But I want to execute javascript (that relies on those variables) when the template finishes rendering.

The html renders fine, but I gave it here for reference anyway.

HTML Template:

```html
<template name="cityDataset">
    {{#each airports}}
    <li>{{name}}
        <ul>
            <li>{{description}}</li>
            <li><a href="{{mapLink}}" target="_blank">Directions from...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Javascript file:

```js
Template.cityDataset.helpers({
  airports: function() {
    console.log("helper-name: " + this.name);        // New York City
    console.log("helper-country: " + this.country);  // United States

    return CityDatasets.findOne({name: this.name, country: this.country}).airports;
  },
});

Template.cityDataset.rendered = function() {
    console.log("name: " + this.name);        // undefined
    console.log("country: " + this.country);  // undefined

    // I want to do stuff here! But I can't get the name and country :(
    //
    // doSomethingCoolToDOM(this.name, this.country);

}
```

The result I get in the console is this:

```
> helper-name: New York City
> helper-country: United States
> name: undefined
> country: undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of rendered, you need to use [this.data](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_data) to access the template's data context.

```js
Template.cityDataset.rendered = function() {
  console.log("name: " + this.data.name);
  console.log("country: " + this.data.country);
}
```